# How to allocate array size in Python

Tags: python, arrays

Python newbie here. I've searched quite a bit for a solution to this but nothing quite fits what I need. I would like to allocate an empty array at the start of my program that has a rows and b columns. I came up with a solution but encountered an interesting problem that I didn't expect. Here's what I had:

```
a = 7
b = 5
array_ab = [['?'] * b] * a
```

which produces

```
[['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']]
```

However, if I try to change a single element, it treats every row as the same object and effectively changes the entire column to that element. So for example

```
array_ab[4][2] = '1'
```

produces

```
[['?', '?', '1', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '1', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '1', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '1', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '1', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '1', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '1', '?', '?']]
```

Clearly I need a better way to create the blank array than by multiplication. Is there a solution to this in python? (It was so simple in FORTRAN!)

Comment: You might want to check out `numpy`. It's a module that deals a lot with arrays.

Comment: It doesn't *treat* every row as the same object, every row *is* the same object; multiplication has just created many references to that object. You don't usually need to allocate a list in Python in advance, they grow as you append items to them. So your approach to the underlying problem may not be ideal - what exactly are you planning to do?

Comment: Tim, thanks for the clarification! I am writing a text adventure and wanted to create a little "minimap" grid that starts blank but fills in as you move, changing the '?' to '1'.

Comment: @JohannesKepler: OK, in that case Shurane's answer is indeed the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
In [12]: a = 5

In [13]: b = 7

In [14]: array_ab = [ [ '?' for i in xrange(a) ] for j in xrange(b) ]

In [15]: array_ab
Out[15]:
[['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']]

In [16]: array_ab[4][2] = '1'

In [17]: array_ab
Out[17]:
[['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '1', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']]
```

In particular, you're using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [xrange](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange).

Answer (score 4):

Use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) `[['?'] * b for _ in range(a)]`:

```
In [1405]: a = 7
      ...: b = 5
      ...: array_ab = [['?'] * b for _ in range(a)]

In [1406]: array_ab
Out[1406]: 
[['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']]

In [1407]: array_ab[4][2] = '1'

In [1408]: array_ab
Out[1408]: 
[['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '1', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']]
```

`['?']*b` is safe, because '?' is an **immutable** string, changing elements of a list of string does not affect the others:

```
In [1419]: a=['a']*5

In [1420]: a[2]=123

In [1421]: a
Out[1421]: ['a', 'a', 123, 'a', 'a']
```

while `[[1,2]]*3` is dangerous, because list is **mutable**, this equals:

```
In [1427]: b=[1,2]
      ...: a=[b,b,b] #a is just a list of b's references
      ...: print a
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

changing elements of the inner list `b` does not affect the contents of `a`.

Comment: Shouldn't you still get mirroring with the array multiplication?

Comment: @Shurane, no, because ['?']*b makes a list of immutable strings

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use your array for numerical computations, and can live with importing an external library, then I would suggest looking at `numpy`.
It provides an array class and lots of useful array operations.

Creating an MxN array is simply

```
import numpy as np

A = np.empty((M,N)) # Empty array
B = np.zeros((M,N)) # Array filled with zeros
```

Indexing is then done like

```
x = A[i,j]
A[4,2] = 1

row1 = A[0, :] # or simply A[0]
```

Comment: +1 on `numpy` for anything computationally expensive.

Comment: If you know the type of the array you can do even np.empty((M,N),dtype='int') and so on...

Comment: He is using string arrays: how do non numeric data types play with numpy? What about arbitrary data types?

Answer (score 3):

**The problem is here:**

```
array_ab = [['?'] * 4] * 3
```

The problem is caused by the fact that python chooses to pass lists around by object reference. **Because list is mutable object.**

But since lists might get pretty large, rather than shifting the whole list around memory, Python chooses to just use a reference ('pointer' in C terms). If you assign one to another variable, you assign just the reference to it. This means that you can have two variables pointing to the same list in memory:

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = a
>>> a[0] = 2
>>> print b
[2]
```

So, in your first line of code you have **`['?'] * 4`**.

Now `['?']` is a pointer to the value `?` in memory, and when you multiply it, you get **`4`** pointers to the same place in memory.

BUT when you change one of the values then Python knows that the pointer needs to change to point to the new value:

```
>>> a = 4 * ['?']
>>> a
['?', '?', '?', '?']]
```

**You can verify the id of the element inside the list:**

```
>>> [id(v) for v in a]
[33302480, 33302480, 33302480, 33302480]
>>> a[0] = 1
>>> a
[1, '?', '?', '?']
```

The problem comes when you multiply this list - you get four copies of the list pointer. 
Now when you change one of the values in one list, all four change together.

The suggested approach is to create a list of the desired length first and then fill in each element with a newly created list:

```
>>> A = [None] * 3
>>> for i in range(3):
...     A[i] = [None] * 4
...
>>> A
[[None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None]]
>>>
```

This generates a list containing 3 different lists of length 4.

**Or You can use list comprehension :**

```
w, h = 4, 3
A = [[None] * w for i in range(h)]
[[None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None]]
```

**Edit 2**

Base on your header, you can't allocate a exact memory for list in advanced. Python list is using some kind of algorithm to over allocate the list size for future additional growth.

[from the source code:](https://github.com/sapamja/python-1/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L41)

```
 /* This over-allocates proportional to the list size, making room
 * for additional growth.  The over-allocation is mild, but is
 * enough to give linear-time amortized behavior over a long
 * sequence of appends() in the presence of a poorly-performing
 * system realloc().
 * The growth pattern is:  0, 4, 8, 16, 25, 35, 46, 58, 72, 88, ...
 */
```

Comment: +1 for an explanation as well as a solution

Comment: Very informative, thank you! List comprehension definitely solves my problem best.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `id()`, that's useful to look at the references of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = 7
b = 5
array_ab = []
for i in range(a):
    array_ab.append([])
    for j in range(b):
        array_ab[i].append('?')
```

This code:

```
array_ab[4][2] = '1'
```

Will change `array_ab` to:

```
[['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], 
['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], 
['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], 
['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], 
['?', '?', '1', '?', '?'], 
['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], 
['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']]
```